# Can REST URLs send back UI rendering hints as metadata?

Tags: rest, metadata

I could not find a definitive document mentioning if UI rendering hints can be sent back as REST metadata or not. First of all, what all can be classified as REST metadata? Surely, data type of attribute can be metadata but can presentation hints like whether an attribute is single-valued or multi-valued also be described metadata? What about "ishidden" and "isReadOnly"? As per my understanding information like min/max/regexp/fixed value are OK as metadata but not sure if anything related to presentation hints like the one I mentioned above are good candidates for REST metadata? Any pointers would be of utmost help.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: You can send even a HTML fragment or javascript code (aka code on demand http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7 )  if you want, so sending this UI meta data is not an issue I think. Btw thierry templier is right, you should send UI meta only to clients which need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honnestly you are free to send back to the REST client what you want in your payload. However I'm not sure that it's a good idea to always use these UI-oriented metadata. As a matter of fact, you can also have applications that consume data without having UI issues.

You could implement a mechanism that let you select the metadata level you want to return to the REST client within the content negociation (Conneg based on the header `Accept`) in a similar way that what OData does. Here is a sample below:

```
GET serviceRoot/People
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
```

You could imagine the following values for the header `Accept`:

- **No metadata**: application/json;metadata=none
- **Structural metadata** (property type, ...): application/json;metadata=minimal
- **Validation metadata** (useful to determine the expected values for properties): application/json;metadata=validation
- **UI rendering metadata** (readonly, ...): application/json;metadata=rendering

You can then structure the content as described below:

```
{
    "property1": "value",
    // Structural
    "property1@metadata": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "property2": 10,
    // Structural + validation
    "property2@metadata": {
        "type": "integer"
        "minValue": 2,
        "maxValue": 15
    },
    "property3": 10,
    // Structural + ui rendering
    "property3@metadata": {
        "type": "integer"
        "minValue": 2,
        "maxValue": 15,
        "readOnly": true,
        "hidden": false
    }
}
```

If you want to have a look at how metadata are handled within OData v4, you can use the following links from odata.org:

- **Basic tutorial** - http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/
- **Advanced tutorial** - http://www.odata.org/getting-started/advanced-tutorial/

**EDIT: in a comment, [inf3rno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607033/inf3rno) underlines the header `Prefer` could also be used to describe the meta level required.**

Here is a sample of use below:

```
GET serviceRoot/People
Accept: application/json
Prefer: metadata=rendering
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Maybe he could use the prefer header http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7240 to describe the meta level required.

Comment: Yes, you're right! The prefer header could be a good fit. I'll add this in my response. Thanks very much!

Comment: I really love your approach but how to update the metadata on rendering level? Let's assume I want to change "hidden: false" to "hidden: true". What's an appropriate way to do that?